# In the Notes app (iOS 12.4), how to remove "All on my iPhone", "Notes", and "Recently Deleted" folders

Tags: notes.app

In the Notes app, which I am using offline, say I write a note and I put it in a folder I create called "Ool's Folder". Say I then delete the note and create another one.

At this point, I have four (!) folders showing, namely "All on My iPhone", "Notes", "Ool's Folder", and "Recently Deleted".

How can I get only a single folder showing, namely "Ool's Folder". I have tried the method of swiping left to delete, but this only works on "Ool's Folder" and not on any of three folders that I would actually like to delete.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are notes in Recently Deleted, the folder will be there.

There's nothing much you can do about system folders. I tend to ignore them unless required. Or not make a folder at all. This keeps everything simplified(relatively).